# Are there any PHP -> LLVM IR translators?

Tags: php, llvm

I need to compile PHP source to LLVM bitcode. I've tried Raven PHP (http://code.roadsend.com/rphp) and it's able to do what i want, but the project seems to be dead. So i wanted to check for some more possible projects.

After that I found phpllvm PECL extension (http://svn.php.net/viewvc/svn/pecl/llvm/). I even have almost made it to run with trunk LLVM, but after closely looking on the code, i figured, that LLVM code is being generated only when according PHP function is being executed. Unfortunately, it's not what i want.

So i wonder, if there are more projects for translating PHP to LLVM and if not - what's the best way, from your point of view, to implement such thing?

[**About LLVM:**](http://llvm.org/)

> The LLVM Project is a collection of modular and reusable compiler and
>   toolchain technologies.

Comment: I know this is old, but if generating LLVM when a function is run is not the behavior you want, what is it that you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't say what your goal is.  If it is simply better performance and easy availablity, you might consider the [HipHop PHP compiler](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/).

Comment: Thanks, that might be useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

With llvm ir byte code  you can execute php in gralvm!